# NSToolbar: how do I initialise with a selected item?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4.2, osx-snow-leopard

I have a Mac OS application with a preferences window with a NSToolbar on it.

I have also a custom subview under it and other 3 custom views that are loaded inside the first one when the user clicks on one of the options.

So far, so good. Now I realised the first item is not selected by default when the window is loaded.

I see no options in the inspectors, except the "selectable", which I used. But there is no "selected". Should I do it programmatically? How?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NSToolbar` has a `-setSelectedItemIdentifier:` method that you can use in your `-windowDidLoad` method.